# This page isn’t working .Localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

> This page isn’t working
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

I have published Web API project on IIS with all configurations.

Already tried things:

1. .Net Core hosting bundle. (added)
   and I can see it in IIS target website modules.
2. IIS settings checked many times.

Note:

1. API URL is just returning a method which have string return type which is
   But when I hit another method which have list return type it shows the message "localhost is currently unable to handle this request".
2. Without publishing project on IIS it is working perfectly fine.

Default methods controller are working perfectly fine which returns string.

But when I call other methods in the controller it shows error message *"Localhost is currently unable to handle the request"*
*URL not working (calling default method which returns string)

[image]

working URL (calling another method in controller)

[image]

Comment: Please, include some methods that are not working in the question so we can take a look

Comment: You are connecting to a Server so the Server must be running before you try to connect.  The error message says the connection is failing which can occur for lots of reasons.  Here are some 1)   Server is not running 2) You are trying to connect to a server on local machine when server is on another machine 3)  The port is being blocked 4)  There is no route to server.  Try using both IP address and Server Name.  Make sure you can Ping to server from client.

Comment: "when I call other methods in the controller", how? You have to edit your question to reveal the relevant code."Localhost is currently unable to handle the request", you need to show the entire error message/page, ideally a screenshot if you don't know which part to show.

Comment: Not working method->[Produces("application/json")]
        [HttpGet("GetTaskStatus")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Status>> GetTaskStatus()
        {}    below is the default method in controller->         public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value4", "value2" };
        } Sorry for lait reply

Comment: Have you tried to applied these solution to get the really exception? Besides, did you get any error message in event viewer application or system event?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1- enable  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); in startup.cs file.
Now execption will show in broweser instead of "Localhost is currently unable to handle the request"

Issue was with the connection string after adding userid and password in connection string my issue resolved.
Thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: thanks, adding `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`  was helpful to find the error

Answer (score 2):

Make sure this part comes on top in your Configure method in Startup file

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
     app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "learning_todo_jwt v1"));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error code you get is just `500`, not `500.x`, then [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0#500-internal-server-error) describes what's going on:

> The app starts, but an error prevents the server from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error occurs within the app's code during startup or while creating a response. The response may contain no content, or the response may appear as a *500 Internal Server Error* in the browser. The Application Event Log usually states that the app started normally. From the server's perspective, that's correct. The app did start, but it can't generate a valid response. Run the app at a command prompt on the server or enable the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log to troubleshoot the problem.

So you need to figure out what went wrong in your app.

There are more troubleshooting steps under the [Troubleshoot on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0#troubleshoot-on-iis) section. In my experience, the most useful troubleshooting step is [enabling the stdout log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-iis) in web.config.

```
<aspNetCore processPath="bin\myapp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\stdout" />
```

That should hopefully show you an error message in that file and you can search for that error.

Comment: My App is running fine without publishing it on iis on local machine and all the responses are working fine.

Comment: But after publishing it on iis it is showing that "Localhost is currently unable to handle the request". I have added the screen shots in Question now. Please check to see the response.

Comment: Right. I understand that. Going through the troubleshooting steps I mentioned will help you find what the problem is.